# How can I trigger my build on Azure DevOps using YAML file?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

How can I trigger my build on Azure DevOps using YAML file?
I did a merge on my master branch. Build was tiggered.
Then I did a pull request from master to

- release/development
- release/staging
- release/production

in this order. Only the merge on release/production triggered the build.

Why? To make sure it is not just a question of the correct version of the YAML file on the correct branch I repeated these actions a second time. Same result.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
  branches:
   include:
     - master
     - release/production
     - release/development
     - release/staging

pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

name: $(Date:yy).$(Date:MM).$(Rev:r)

variables:
  
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: $(Solution)

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: $(Solution)
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Why the master and production build are starting and not the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set the trigger on the web UI for the build pipeline. The triggers set on the web UI will override that set in the YAML files.

If the triggers set on the web UI only includes the **`master`** and **`release/production`** branches, the pipeline will only be triggered for the two branches.

[image]

To avoid this, you can disable the triggers set on the web UI and only keep the triggers set in the YAML files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you merge yaml to other branches? The build may not start if it is not in a branch. An example of the development branch:

[image]